# Unable to click an element in the webpage

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate an element and click on that element to go to the other page but the element is not getting clicked but it is not showing any errors or warning. Its just highlighting the element but it is not getting clicked

i am using the following

```
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
Thread.sleep(10000);
WebElement elements = driver.findElement(By.id("menuItem_Permissions"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elements).click().perform();
```

Comment: What happens when you call `elements.click()` directly (not using Actions). Which browser are you testing on? HTML code of the element will also be helpful. Also, your `WebDriverWait` is not really being used, as you haven't used it to wait find the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Implicit Wait and a bit of this trick

```
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait( driver, 10 )
    .until( ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
    (By.id("menuItem_Permissions")));

    WebElement wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,                            
    10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));

    Actions scrollToElement = new Actions(driver);
    scrollToElement.moveToElement(wait).perform();              
    element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your action string you want to use `.build()` - so adding it like this.

```
action.moveToElement(elements).click().build().perform();
```

And as @Faiz has mentioned, you have declared a WebDriverWait command but its not being called anywhere, not from what you have posted. Avoid the `Thread.sleep` is where possible. Thats not causing the issue however.

You shouldn't need to use an actions builder for one element, just try using `elements.click();`